# C#: Simulate key press in game

Tags: c#, keyboard, key, controls

I want to be able to control a game (Planes) from a C# application. I have tried various methods, including

- SendKeys.SendWait("W")
- SendKeys.Send("W")
- InputSimulator
- SendInput

If i open notepad and run my code I can see that all of these methods work (The letters WASD is written according to the code). However when i open my game it does not react to these inputs.

Anyone have an idea to a better approach?

Comment: It depends on the game. Some games can be really hard to simulate keys into. You basically need to know how the game intercepts keys.

Comment: I there a way I can figure this out?

Comment: Sometimes. I've tried simulating keys into games that don't welcome the methods mentioned above and failed.

Comment: You could try using Spy++ to see what messages the process gets when you press "W".

Comment: try this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544271/how-can-i-send-keyboard-input-to-a-opengl-directx-game-window

Comment: I tried to using Spy++ but I could not figure this out, however the AutoIT did the trick. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @terrybozzio Do you happen to know why AutoIt succeeds where SendKeys fails?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Should be;

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{W}");
```